# Laravel Sanctum XHR request returns me a 401 - "Unauthenticated."

Tags: laravel

I am trying out Laravel Sanctum and unfortunately I have a problem and hope you can help me.

I have several blade pages that I call up via the web route. For example `'/', 'about-us'` and `/dashboard`. The dashboard is only visible to users who are logged in.

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
```

In the dashboard, I have a tab where the logged-in user can view all other users. Here I send a get fetch call to the api route with Vanilla JS.

**api.php**

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

**My JS in the blade file looks like this:**

```js
async function send(method, url = "/api/users") {

    const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
            method: method,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }, 2000);
    const content = await rawResponse.json();
    return content;
}
```

**Problem:** But I get a 401 here `Object { message: "Unauthenticated." }`.  Why and what do I have to do to make it work?

**My thinking so far**.
As I understand it, Laravel sets a `laravel_session` and an `XSRF-token` cookie when it is called. If I fire the request against the webroute, laravel recognises me as the user. But if i fire the same request against the laravel api route i am not logged in for laravel. So I have to provide something in my request. I had tried to include the XSRF token in the request header. Like that:

```js
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
// ...
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
},
```

But that didn't work either.

**Note:** I have not configured anything else in Laravel to sanctum. I only ran the migration (`personal_access_token`). But the table is always empty.

My **Kernel.php** file:

```php
  'api' => [
    // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

Comment: Sanctum need token to sync with front-end. Since you say that `personal_access_tokens` always empty, it impossible to use that api. Except you put api out of auth:sanctum middleware. I suggest you to put your api in web.php instead api.php, and put on auth middleware, so just logged user can access that.

Comment: @HafidMaulana Thank you! I think it is a good solution to put it to the web routes and use the auth:web middleware. That will works, I checked already out :-). Do you think it is possible to use sanctum for both (api & web)? In my Kernel.php the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,` is out commented.

Comment: Why does one page have middleware `['auth', 'verified']` and the other `auth:sanctum`? Shouldn't both have the same auth mechanism?

Comment: @miken32 Because auth:web does not work for the api route.

Comment: include the Authorization header in your request. `headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }`

Comment: Isn't it true, that with Sanctum you first have to make a call, to get the cookie and then make the call to get your users?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Thx for your comment! :-) Yes it seems so. As I understand it, it has to go like this. I had already tried it with the csrf token. But it didn't work. But if bearer then it must be a JWT token, right? That means I would have to get the token after the successful login and put it into the localstorage or into a cookie. But how do I get the token after a successful login?